# Does addEventListener work in a while loop?

Tags: javascript, audio, while-loop, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to loop through a number of elements to change the audio source of a single audio element, play it, and once ended, change the new src and play it until the loop has gone through all elements:

```
var contentAudio = new Audio();;

function audioLoop(index, audioModel) {

    while (index < audioModel.length) {
        var audio = contentAudio;
        audio.src = audioModel[index].src;
        audio.play()
        audio.addEventListener('ended', 
            function () {
                index++;
            });
    }
    console.log('done');

}
```

It seems that adding the event listener is not working. The audio does not play and I am stuck in an endless loop. The audio ended event is never triggered. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop is synchronous so it doesn't wait for your `ended` event. Here is what I'm suggesting:

```
var contentAudio = new Audio();

function audioLoop(index, audioModel) {

    (function process(done) {
      if (index >= audioModel.length) {
        done(); return;
      }
      var audio = contentAudio;
      audio.src = audioModel[index].src;
      audio.play()
      audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        index++;
        process(done);
      });
    })(function () {
      console.log('done');
    });

}
```

Also is `audioModel` an array. If so I think you should be using `audioModel[index].src` instead of `audioModel.src`.

Comment: yes it is an array, and yes as you say it should be `audioModel[index].src` thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: is there a way to deregister the event listener?

Comment: You can use `removeEventListener` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener